# How to uninstall Java SE 6 on OS X 10.11?

Tags: java, macos

I found an old copy of Adobe CS4 that I had tucked away. I decided to install on my 2014 MBP as I was interested in running Illustrator for some vector images I was wanting to use. It required that I install legacy Java SE 6 runtime. I did so, but looks like I'm still having issues so I decided to get rid of it. I've uninstalled Adobe, but I'm not sure how to get rid of the deprecated java version as I have no other use for it.

There do seem to be guides on uninstalling Java, but I don't want to do this as I still need the current version for other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove Java 6... From [How to properly uninstall Java 6 on OSX?](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2014-February/006388.html), do the following:

> Remove the "system" JVM installed and maintained by Software Update
>
> ```
> % sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
> ```
>
> Remove any Java Developer Previews
>
> ```
> % sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0*.jdk
> ```
>
> Do NOT remove any content in the JavaVM.framework. Those items are
>   required by Java 7, 8, 9+ as well as Java SE 6. No modern version of
>   OS X has a Java JDK inside there anyway.

Comment: Don't forget this directory: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/ and this is a good place to look to re-enable Java 6 https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202643

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find this path in macOS 10.12. Instead I found this path:

```
%sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0*.jdk
```